# Crystal Reports Suppress On Zero

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a summary reports that looks at all stock items, available sizes, sales and transactions.

The report consists

- Stock Reference
- Weight (ton,load, net etc)
- Sub report containing transaction data

All the items are in a group header within the main report.

I wanted to be able to hide the header if an item from the sub report was Zero.

I set up a shared variable which passes the quantity from the sub report to the main report, however this is not processed until the group header is displayed.

To compensate i duplicated everything in the group header and placed it in the group footer (including the shared variable form the sub report).

My thinking was that i could suppress the group header permanently and the group footer conditionally if the shared variable is 0 (if {@SharedQuantity} = 0 then true).

Currently if i suppress the group header the whole report is blank. If i dont suppress the header the footer acts correctly, suppressing rows on items that dont have a quantity.

I assumed that suppressing items still meant that they where processed and hence the shared variable would still be set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the above was to suppress all the fields within the sub report in the group header, then setting the group header as suppress if blank. This way the shared variable was still populated and the conditional suppress on the group footer worked as expected.